# Flask Flash message not showing after redirecting to the same page

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a simple web page where the user selects a file from their computer and then presses an "Upload" button, after which a python script will be initiated with that file as an input.

However, I'm trying to get it so that if the user is uploading a file that will throw an error, a Flash message will show on the same page (without any redirection). In my current attempt, the flash message isn't showing when I choose to upload a purposefully erroneous file.

Also, as another question, is it possible to (within app.py) check for certain backend *python* error messages that will arise once I initiate the script (the ones that will show in the terminal)?

Anyways, here is the relevant code:

**app.py:**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash("No file chosen", 'danger')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file', 'danger')
            return redirect(request.url)
        elif not allowed_file(file.filename):
            flash('Incorrect file extenstion. Must be .TXT!', 'danger')
            return redirect(request.url)
        elif file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #
            # Process the file (omitted here)
            #

            proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {} -p {} -s {} -m {}'.format(file.filename, period, space, affiliation), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            return redirect(url_for('results'))
        else:
            # THIS PART IS NOT WORKING!
            return redirect(request.path)
            flash('There is an affiliation missing from your Place list.', 'danger')
    return render_template('index.html', template_file=app.config['TEMPLATE_FILE'])
```

**html template (layout.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Author Script</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div> 
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Would it help if you do the flash message first and then the redirect? Like this:

```
        flash('There is an affiliation missing from your Place list.', 'danger')
        return redirect(request.path)
```

edit:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash("No file chosen", 'danger')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file', 'danger')
        return redirect(request.url)
    elif not allowed_file(file.filename):
        flash('Incorrect file extenstion. Must be .TXT!', 'danger')
        return redirect(request.url)
    elif file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        try:
            #
            # Process the file (omitted here)
            #

            proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {} -p {} -s {} -m {}'.format(file.filename, period, space, affiliation), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            return redirect(url_for('results'))

        except Exception as e:
            print("type error: " + str(e)) # --> to answer your question on showing errors in console
            flash('There is an affiliation missing from your Place list.', 'danger')
            return redirect (request.path)
    return render_template('index.html', template_file=app.config['TEMPLATE_FILE'])
```

Comment: Are there any other app config variables set besides uploadfolder?

Comment: yes, I also have a SECRET_KEY variable and a TEMPLATE_FILE variable.

Comment: you could try and wrap iyour code in try-except function. I'm still trying to understand how your current code will ever reach that final else statement and what kind of file it has to be. I would advise to add more if/elif statements to rule out any files that should not succeed in actual uploading. See my updated answer for an attempt. Hope it helps.

Comment: So when I try your new code and test it with an erroneous file upload, it does the same thing still - it redirects me to the 'results' url (as it would if the input is correct), only it turns up blank because the error prevents the script from forming a proper result.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I meant by saying you need to add more if statements to rule out certain files or file formats that should not lead to the results redirect. In your original code you only check if a file is selected and file extension. If that isn't enough you should work on that. How else would your app know which files should be prevented from uploading?

Comment: Right, but that's why I was asking if there's a way to connect Flask with backend python errors. I know what python error is raised when I upload the erroneous input file (i.e. the traceback error in the terminal), but I don't understand how to have Flask "see" that python error, so that I can add a corresponding "if" statement.

Comment: Am I correct stating that the error occurs in code you have not posted here yet? I suspect that it is somewhere where it says " process the file..".  Maybe if you put that function in a try except in a similar way I posted above you can catch all errors and print or send flash message.

Answer (score 2):

To show the flash messages, you need to specify a space for it. Probably you forget to add space for the flash messages. I encourage you to check out [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/quickstart/#message-flashing).

You can do it by creating

`messages.html`

paste the following code in it

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for category, message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% if error %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
{% endif %}

{% if msg %}
  <div class="alert alert-success">{{msg}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Make sure you call this messages.html inside the layout.html. Like this

```
{% include 'includes/_messages.html' %}
```

to make it show more beautiful you can put it in a  like this

```
<div class='container'>
    {% include 'includes/_messages.html' %}
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1168

This link suggests configs of APPLCATION_ROOT or caches would solve/"fix" the problem. Try these out firsts.

But what really did it for me was adding get_flashed_message in the methods.

```
from flask import get_flashed_messages


@app.route('/')
def upload():
    get_flashed_messages()
    ....
```